# bun - How to get output from spawn

Tags: node.js, spawn, bun

I'd like to the read the output of an async spawn in real time with bun

```
import { spawn } from "bun";
const { stdout } = spawn("some command");

// doesn't work with bun (works with node.js)
stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
    ...
})
```

In the example shown on the bun website, you have to wait for the process to complete before getting the output:
https://github.com/oven-sh/bun#bunspawn--spawn-a-process

Answer (score 3):

You can `for await` `Subprocess.stdout` to read chunks from the ReadableStream asynchronously.

```
const proc = Bun.spawn({
    cmd: ["some", "command"]
});

for await (const chunk of proc.stdout) {
    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(chunk));
}
```

(TextDecoder is used here because `chunk` is a Uint8Array)